# Solo mining error

Tags: bitcoin-core, solo-mining, guiminer

so i have been trying to set up my pc to solo mine for almost a week now. i am using bitcoin core and guiminer v0.10.2. i have gotten to the point where i can start mining, but when i do i get this error.

> 2015-05-25 13:35:14: Running command: poclbm.exe username:password@localhost:8332 --device=0 --platform=0 --verbose -r1 
>   2015-05-25 13:35:14: Listener for "Solo mine" started
>   2015-05-25 13:35:15: Listener for "Solo mine": WARNING: ADL missing (no AMD platform?), temperature control is disabled
>   2015-05-25 13:35:15: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:15, checking for stratum...
>   2015-05-25 13:35:15: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:15, started OpenCL miner on platform 0, device 0 (GeForce GTX 750 Ti)
>   2015-05-25 13:35:17: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:17, no response to getwork, using as stratum
>   2015-05-25 13:35:18: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:18,  [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   2015-05-25 13:35:19: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:19, IO errors - 1, tolerance 2
>   2015-05-25 13:35:21: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:21,  [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   2015-05-25 13:35:22: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:22, IO errors - 2, tolerance 2
>   2015-05-25 13:35:23: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:23,  [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   2015-05-25 13:35:24: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:24, IO errors - 3, tolerance 2
>   2015-05-25 13:35:24: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:24, No more backup servers left. Using primary and starting over.
>   2015-05-25 13:35:25: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:25,  [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   2015-05-25 13:35:26: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:26, IO errors - 1, tolerance 2
>   2015-05-25 13:35:27: Listener for "Solo mine": localhost:8332 25/05/2015 13:35:27,  [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   2015-05-25 13:35:27: Listener for "Solo mine" shutting down

i tryed to download an ald driver, but none support my OS.
Can anyone help me figure out the problem?
im on windows 8.1. thanks

Comment: What kind of ASIC miner are you using?

Comment: I'm not. I'm just using my GeForce GTX 750 TI to mine. I'm very new to all if this. I figured I would give the bitcoin  solo lottery a shot. I was in slush pool but I was only pulling .00000050 per block. Estimated time of my payout was 18 months.

Comment: Any kind of mining without specialized hardware is definitely not worth your time or electricity cost.  Buying actual lottery tickets has a rate of return that's about 100 times better.  So you might want to consider that before deciding to sink more time into this.

Comment: An r-box. Sounds good to me. Will I need an additional power supply? Will this possibly remove the error that I am seeing now? Thanks for the replays guys.

Comment: Ordered 1 r-box. Hopefully this will be a good start. Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You're likely to never ever get the cost back for frying your card. Simply an impossible feat to mine with a graphics card. Invest in a new r -box. You can find them on ebay for about $60-100. You'll earn roughly 0.001 btc per day, which is roughly 30 cents per day.

Answer (score 1):

You will need  power supply.Be sure to get one with appropriate connections to connect to r-box.R-box uses a measley 100 watts,which is nothing but youll mine not much as well.If your looking to get some return on your box i would suggest rent it out on Mining Rig Rentals.There you might regain some cost.I hate to break the blunt truth to you as well but unless you run a 100 Terrahash Farm youll never solomine  a bitcoin.

Comment: Thanks. I ordered one from Amazon. It comes with a power supply. Is it possible to mine with like 4 of then at the same time to increase my hash rate?

Comment: I figured that I would need a lot of power. If I can get a payout from slush pool that does not take 19 months I will be happy. This is just a start for me. I feel I will be trying to build a nice rig. It will just take time and money.

Comment: You can adjust your payouts on slushs pool to lower amounts.I think the ,minimal is 0.001 BTC payout.That will take you roughly a day with a 100 ghs R-Box,depending on pools luck as well!!.Lately slushs pool hasnt had all that much luck.If you want a gaurantee payout in a day go for a PPS(pay per share) pool.

Comment: Thank you. I will check into that when my R-box arrives.

Comment: Personally id mine at www.BTCMP.com.It is pay per share but you can see your progress right in front of you.They do have a minimal payout of 0.001BTC as well .

Comment: Good piece of advice splurge on a 500$ Bitmain Antminer s5.They produce 1 TH/S and burn only 650 watts .Youll like make about 20-25$ per week with it.Not including your cost for electricity.

Comment: Excellent. I will make an account today. Thank you for the info.